# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component with if condition

Tags: javascript, react-native

*I am a new for react native and  JavaScript . This not a advance quection.I just try to compare a string  like in java .but it doesn't work .when run this it also print the if conditions like a sting .

```
 <FlatList 
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={({id },index) => id}
        renderItem={({item}) =>(

          <View style={styles.container}>

            if({item.id} ==1){
              <Text style={styles.textStyle1}>ID is : {item.id}</Text>
            }else{
              <Text >ID is : {item.id}</Text>
            }
               
                <Text style={styles.textStyle2}>Title is :{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle3}>releaseYear is :  {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          </View>
          
          
        )}
      
      />   

 
    
    
    * error
    Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
    
    
    * output in web
    
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHS6.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add code inside JSX elements but you can do the following:

**Add the code inside a block and use [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>

    {
    item.id ==1 ?
      <Text style={styles.textStyle1}>ID is : {item.id}</Text>
    :
      <Text >ID is : {item.id}</Text>
    }
       
        <Text style={styles.textStyle2}>Title is :{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle3}>releaseYear is :  {item.releaseYear}</Text>
  </View>
```

Or you may use [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
   {(function() {
      if (item.id==1) {
        return <Text style={styles.textStyle1}>ID is : {item.id}</Text>;
      } else {
        return <Text >ID is : {item.id}</Text>
      }
    })()}
   
    <Text style={styles.textStyle2}>Title is :{item.title}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle3}>releaseYear is :  {item.releaseYear}</Text>
```

Comment: it's work . but i have add {} and try to use if condition it doesn't work

Comment: I will add one more method that will help with your case

Comment: Immediately Invoked Function Expressions not work for me

Comment: Can you explain how it doesnt work ? error or what?

Comment: I make  another condition with immediate invoked and I check it(item.title =='Inception') but it didn't return true and false. i think  it doesn't read

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
{item.id ==1 ? <Text style={styles.textStyle1}>ID is : {item.id}</Text>
     : <Text >ID is : {item.id}</Text>
}
```

Have a look at [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)